# Unable to find local tiledesk widget in angular app

Tags: angular, chat

So I'm trying to integrate a locally built tiledesk chat widget from the source code into my application.

Based on this repo https://github.com/Tiledesk, I downloaded a few repos and set things up accordingly:

1. Tiledesk-server
2. chat21-ionic
3. Tiledesk dashboard
4. Tiledesk cloud functions (deployed to firebase)
5. Tiledesk chat widget.

Then I proceeded to run all, created my account in dashboard, got the project id and the embed js code:

```
<head>
  <script type="application/javascript">
    window.tiledeskSettings=
    {
        projectid: "6571d97415c13c7350b24912"
    };
    (function(d, s, id) {
       var w=window; var d=document; var i=function(){i.c(arguments);};  
       i.q=[]; i.c=function(args){i.q.push(args);}; w.Tiledesk=i; 
       var js, fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];  
       if (d.getElementById(id)) return;   
       js=d.createElement(s);   
       js.id=id; js.async=true; js.src="http://localhost:4600/launch.js"; 
       fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document,'script','tiledesk-jssdk'));
 </script>
</head>
```

The issue I have is when I place this JS code into an empty html file, the script launches and the widget appears.

But when I embed this into an angular app, I get error 404 unable to find http://localhost:4600/launch.js. Im assuming its some permission thingy I need to set on the angular side or maybe on the tiledesk-server side?

[image]

and here's the launch.js file when i put the address in the browser:

[image]